# Sending a Bounding Box from JavaScript to an Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a JavaScript variable which is basically an array of bounding boxes (called `bounds`).  Each array element is in the form of:

```
{
    XHigh: -71.00742992911023,
    XLow: -71.00670274612378,
    YHigh: 42.09467040703646,
    YLow: 42.09458047487587
}
```

And I'm trying to send it to an action method via POST:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Map/GetLocations',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { boxes: bounds },
    success: function(data) {
        // doing something with the result
    }
});
```

On the server, I consume the data into the action method as such:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetLocations(IList<BoundingBox> boxes)
{
    // do something with boxes and return some json
}
```

With the DTO class defined as:

```
public class BoundingBox
{
    public decimal XHigh { get; set; }
    public decimal XLow { get; set; }
    public decimal YHigh { get; set; }
    public decimal YLow { get; set; }
}
```

Within the action method the `boxes` value does contain the correct number of elements that I sent in the POST.  However, all of the decimal values are 0.  I tried changing them to `double`s in the DTO, still 0.0.  I tried changing them to `string`s and they were empty.

Am I missing something in the model binding on how to populate these values?  How can I send this array of objects to my action method?

Comment: Is your Json data formatted exactly as you showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little helper for this problem because I got also stuck with some variations of your problem. I worked around these problems by sending a serialized version of my JS object to the server (using `JSON.stringify()`) and let MVC deserialize it on-the-fly.

The first class I wrote is the `JsonParameterAttribute`. It instructs MVC to use my `TypedJsonBinder` when binding the decorated parameter.

```
public class JsonParameterAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return new TypedJsonBinder();
    }
}
```

The `TypedJsonBinder` takes the decorated parameter's value as string and tries to deserialize it to the parameter's type using the [Json.NET](http://json.net) library in my case. (You can use other deserialization technologies, of course.)

```
public class TypedJsonBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var json = (string) bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).ConvertTo(typeof (string));

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, bindingContext.ModelType);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use the `JsonParameterAttribute` like this:

```
public ActionResult GetLocations([JsonParameter] List<BoundingBox> boxes)
{
    // ...
}
```

And don't forget to serialize:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Map/GetLocations',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { boxes: JSON.stringify(bounds) },
    success: function(data) {
        // doing something with the result
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Here's hoping that the frameworks and whatnot that this project uses don't get in the way of a custom model binder (or maybe they have a model binder for this and I just don't know), but this got my proof-of-concept for the functionality working.

Answer (score 0):

If your Json is formatted exactly as you have shown it, then I think it will need to be of this form instead:

```
{ 
    XHigh: -71.00742992911023, 
    XLow: -71.00670274612378, 
    YHigh: 42.09467040703646, 
    YLow: 42.09458047487587 
}
```

Json deserialization will choke on the `=` character.

**Edit**

If you change

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult GetLocations(IList<BoundingBox> boxes) 
{ 
    // do something with boxes and return some json 
}
```

to

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult GetLocations(BoundingBoxRequest request) 
{ 
    // do something with boxes and return some json 
} 

public class BoundingBoxRequest
{
    public IList<BoundingBox> Boxes { get; set; }
}
```

then you *should* be able to send that back and have it deserialized.

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  I was using the `:` in my code.  (That'll teach me not to hand-copy code from another workstation and just login to SO on that workstation instead.)  Question updated.

Comment: Actually, maybe it wasn't my mistake... Looking now in Firebug I see that the Watch values use `=` while the code creates it with `:`.  Is that just how Firebug is displaying things, or is there actually meaning behind it?

Comment: The method argument still has the correct number of items in the collection, but all of the decimal values therein are still `0`.

Comment: Would you be able to post the JSON from just prior to the Ajax call? I am finding it really hard to figure out why the the deserialization isn't working, so this might help narrow it down.